# How to change fontWeight globally in MaterialUI/React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use fontweight 300 globally in my Material UI React project, however the default setting is 400. I only figured out how to override fontWeight on a specific component (like h3 in the code below), so i ask for help in setting it globally for all Material UI Components that i will be using in the future.

```
overrides: {
            MuiTypography: {
               h3: {
                fontWeight: 300
            }},
            MuiTableCell:{
              root:{
                fontWeight: 200
              }
            },
          },
```

In the code example below i change FontFamily and borderRadius for all components at the same time using createMuiTheme, but i don't know how to set FontWeight to all Material UI components at the same time.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
      'Sora',
      'sans-serif'
    ].join(','),
  },
  shape:{
    borderRadius:12
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

tru to add `""` to `fontWeight`

```
 h3: {
  "fontWeight": 200,
},
```

Comment: That's not the case. I can set FontWeight to specific heading like h3, but i can't find a formula to do it to all Material UI Components at the same time. I can change FontFamily and borderRadius for all components using createMuiTheme, but i don't know how to set FontWeight to all components at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `allVariants` property you can use in your theme's typography configuration:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

// Create a theme instance.
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    allVariants: {
      fontWeight: 300,
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```